# One rubber feet on MacBook Pro (circa 2012) has come off - can I just tape over it and call it a day?

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro, physical-damage, physical-wear

The rubber feet on my MacBook Pro (circa-2012) came off, and to my surprise, there is now a hole through the base of my laptop. You can actually see the insides of the laptop from the hole, which is obviously a red flag for water damage.

The Ruber Feet from Apple is pretty much impossible (and probably expensive) to find in my country. Currently, I've just put three layers of tape over it.

What exactly should I do at this point? Is tape enough, or should I try to stick some kind of a rubber piece over it?

(To be clear, I don't care about the laptop being a bit imbalanced when kept on a table.)

This is what I'm talking about, by the way:-

[image: Rubber Feet]

EDIT: 2 months later, I can confirm that Duct Tape does the trick. Unless you *really* care about aesthetics, ordering new rubber feet may be a waste of time and energy for you.

Comment: Normally you can buy them cheaply from third parties on Ebay and they will often ship worldwide. Just make sure you are buying exactly what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix anything with duck tape, but you can find cheap rubber feet for Macbook Pro on Ebay and Amazon as well.

Comment: The tape did the trick! It's lasted for 2 months now. Thanks!